# vim: How to remove spaces in the middle of lines

Tags: vim

Here is the problem :
In the project I'm working on, tabs are forbidden whatsoever and we are only told to use spaces.
However sometimes, I end up editing a legacy source file that contains tabs for both indentation and code alignment.

Example of code using tabs (with tab characters shown as "|>>>") :

```
|>>>int a =||>>>|>>>0;
|>>>int foobar =|>>>10;
|>>>int toto =|>|>>>4;
```

This is a sample, but you must consider that the whole file is full of it, so much that it can't be corrected by hand.

I usually do a simple search-replace like this to replace tabulation woth spaces :

```
:%s/\t/    /g
```

But the code ends up like this :

```
    int a =            0;
    int foobar =    10;
    int toto =        4;
```

with all the value unaligned.

What I want is a command that can remove useless space, but not indentation, in order to obtain something like this :

```
    int a = 0;
    int foobar = 10;
    int toto = 4;
```

i.e. every set of 2+ spaces must go down to only 1 space, except indentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set `expandtab` so vim does use spaces instead of tab, and then use the `:retab!` function. (see `:h expandtab` and `:h retab!`).

This keeps the layout as it is (like it should). The alignment of the variable assignment is a matter of style, a linter may help here. Else your answer is perfectly fine for removing the whitespaces in the middle.

Comment: Sir, I did not know of this command. You just changed my life !

Answer (score 5):

The command that answers the question is the following :

```
:%s/\([^ ]\+ \) \+/\1/g
```

(please note the blank spaces before and after the `\)`)

This will search every occurrence that has a non-blank precedence and replace the following set of spaces by only one space.

This will, however, leave a single trailing space on lines that had multiple trailing spaces. To correct that, use the command :

```
:%s/ *$//
```